# What is the name of the ceramic artist who created this large platter?

Tags: united-states

I am trying to find the name of the name of the ceramic artist who made this large platter. I think it is an American piece made by a woman. I’d like to know her name.

[image: Large ceramic platter with floral and leaf motifs]

Comment: What do you know about the platter? Do you have any idea of when and where it was manufactured?

Comment: Is this history related?  Will historical sources and methods help?

Comment: There are typically markings related to who made it in the underside.